# Release task - copy a file located on another Azure Devops Repository

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, release

I've got a Release/Pipeline working perfectly. The pipeline create the artifacts and the release release them on specific servers.

But one of my task that do the release is a powershell script and I cannot store it on the repo used by our developer (they can delete it by mistake); I would like to store it on another Azure devops repository.

Is there a way through  a task running in a release A (linked to a repository A) , to download a file from another repo B. ?

Comment: Have you checked the following replies? Are they helpful?

Comment: So your developer can delete a file from git **by mistake**? All that `filter-branch` stuff by mistake?

Answer (score 4):

If you use YAML pipeline, you can [check out multiple repositories in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops). Since you use Azure Repos Git repositories in the same organization, you can use the inline syntax.

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: git://MyProject/MyRepo # Azure Repos Git repository in the same organization
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put the PS script in repo B, and in the release add repo B as [a source artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources---tfvc-git-and-github).

[image]

Now, the release will download the script to the artifacts folder in the agent.